# how to get the list item id from menuInfo on a ContextMenu

Tags: android

When I run the debugger I can look that `ContextMenuInfo menuInfo` variable from the method `onCreateContextMenu` and see that it holds the id of the list item that was long pressed on but how can I get that value to use?

**EDIT**
here is where i need the information

```
@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
        if(mNum == 1){
            menu.setHeaderTitle("Incident List Menu");
            menu.add(Menu.NONE,6,0,"- Take Photo");
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, INCIDENT_DELETE, 1, "- Delete");
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, INCIDENT_DELETE_ALL, 2, "- Delete All");
        }else if(mNum == 2){
            Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(StatusList.STATUS_URI,new String[] {StatusList.STATUS_PERMISSIONS},StatusList.STATUS_ID+"="+, selectionArgs, sortOrder)
            Log.d("MainActivity", "status list");
        }else if(mNum == 3){
            menu.setHeaderTitle("Distribution List Menu");
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, DL_DELETE, 0, "- Delete");
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, DL_DELETE_ALL, 1, "- Delete All");
        }else if(mNum == 4){

        }else if(mNum == 5){

        }
    }
```

I need the ID here to make a query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the supplied `ContextMenuInfo` object to be an `AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo` object, then use `info.position` or `info.id` or whatever.

Comment: Hey Commons, I am getting a class cast exception when I do this.
AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info;         
info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl cannot be cast to android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterContextMenuInfo